# How do I manage multiple cells in Excel that contain random number generation?

Tags: excel, random

I am a social studies teacher currently revising a micro-economics game for one of my classes. I am creating a spread sheet for students to use (on laptops) that tracks a variety of resources they will be collecting and managing throughout the game. At one stage in the game, students collect resources that their fictitious nation possesses, but then they must multiply their collection by a random number to reflect a variety of variables from the 'real world' that could positively or negatively impact that specific resource collection. I have figured out how to format a cell in Excel to randomly generate numbers, but I am using multiple cells each with its own random number generator.

Here is my dilemma/question: As of right now, any time I enter in a value in any cell, or any time I push the F9 key to generate a random number, all cells with the random number generator update. Is there a way to isolate a cell with the random number generator so that only one cell at a time generates a random number?

Comment: pnuts, thanks for responding. This is probably a really dumb question, but could you clarify for me what you meant by "elsewhere refer to A1"? Thanks.

Comment: The random number that is generated acts as a multiplier. Each resource in each round in this game needs it's own randomly generated number to serve as it's own stand alone multiplier so teams have an accurate accounting of their total resources. I figured out how to set up a formula to multiply the resource amount by the random number, but the random number automatically changes after any action in the sheet, thus changing the multiplying factor (and the total amount of resources on hand). So I need a way to have each random number be "stand alone." I hope that helps.

Comment: I am working through a few possibilities, but can I ask you a different, albeit, related question? Is it possible to specify the numbers Excel randomly generates from? I know how to use the RAND formula and the RANDBETWEEN formula, but I would like to have the random number selected from a series of non-consecutive numbers, such as 0,1,1,2,2,3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to utilize something to this effect.  it references cells A1 and B1 where A1 is the row and b1 is the column.  If they match the cells row and column it generates a random number.  The formula below will scream about a circular reference but it works well.  Also this example uses cell D7 as the cell to generate the random number.

in A1 enter 7 'row 7
in B1 enter 4 'column D

```
=IF(A1= ROW(), IF(B1= COLUMN(), RAND(),D7),D7)
```

In fact this may even work better.  All you would have to do is select the cell you want to generate if it is the active cell then it will generate a random number.

```
=IF(CELL("address") = CELL("address",D7), RAND(),D7)
```

In response to your comment

in Cell E6

```
=IF(CELL("address") = CELL("address",E6), RAND(),E6)
```

In Cell D6

```
=E6*400
```

To generate the random number click on E6 and hit F9 to recalc.

Comment: I am going to give it a shot. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Quick clarification (forgive my ignorance) but in the shaded area above where you typed the formula, do you want me to put any value between the parentheses after ROW and COLUMN, or leave them blank? Or, above the shaded are you indicated 7 and 4, would those values be entered into the given formula?

Comment: I just saw your edited/updated formula above (using CELL). Could I have you plug in some cell 'addresses' from my spreadsheet so I can see how it would look? For this specific example: Cell E6 is where I would like the random number generated and I want that number multiplied by 400 in cell D6.

Comment: Dont forget to mark it answered if it solves the problem.  also on your second question about RandBetween it would be a no, you can not do it to select from  non-continuous numbering.

Comment: Woot! The formula using CELL worked!! Thank you so much.